# how to insert into specific column in a new multi column table in sql table

Tags: c#

how can i do this?
is it possible to insert only on two columns when i have more than two columns in sql table please can some one help me to achieve this.

i tried this code below:

```
 SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(shoolmanangmentconn);
                         Conn.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_TestingThatSubjects(INDO, LANGUAGE,BIOLOGY, 
 GEOGRAPHY) VALUES (@IDNO,@LANGUAGE,@BIOLOGY,@GEOGRAPHY)", Conn);
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNO", txtids.Text); 
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LANGUAGE", txtlanguage.Text);    
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i am trying to insert into only at column LANGUAGE without inserting into other columns
please can someone teach me how to do the right thing. (am using wpf c#)

Answer (score 0):

The columns either need to Allow Nulls or have a Default Value:

[image]

This is how you can extend database schema's without breaking existing codebases.

REF: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/07/02/default-value-nullable-column-works-interview-question-week-129/

<sub>ps look into the `using` statement for unmanaged objects, such as the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could pass through `DBNull.Value` for those parameters.

But if you have a default on those columns which you would like to use, then don't have them in the `INSERT` at all:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_TestingThatSubjects(IDNO, LANGUAGE)
VALUES (@IDNO, @LANGUAGE);
```

---

By the way, your code has other issues:

- Dispose your connection and command objects with `using` blocks
- [Avoid `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), as it's not great at guessing the correct datatype and size to pass through.
- It's often neater to keep the SQL in a separate variable. Always declare it `const`, it stops you getting into the habit of interpolating/concatenating dynamic SQL (with the risk of injection).

So your code should look something like this:

```cs
const string query = @"
INSERT INTO tbl_TestingThatSubjects (INDO, LANGUAGE)
VALUES (@IDNO, @LANGUAGE);
";
using(SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(shoolmanangmentconn))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtids.Text; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LANGUAGE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtlanguage.Text;
    Conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```